# How to check about harddisk availability from booting options?

Tags: boot

How to recognise hard disk availability from boot menu option ?

EDIT :

I have Acer Aspire 4520.

How do I know, wether my hard disk is working or not, from boot menu options ?

Comment: Can you clarify this question?  More detail?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'working'? If you want to check if a drive works at all, you can just boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a list of your connected devices, enter the BIOS and you should be able to see if the BIOS is recognizing the harddrive.

If you are looking for the boot menu then follow this:

> Press F2 to enter into the BIOS.  In the BIOS look for the option to enable the F12 boot menu.  Make sure that its enabled. Once you've done that then exit the BIOS making sure to save the changes, and during the boot up you can use F12 to pull up the boot menu.

[found here](http://archxz.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/aspire-4520-4220-4520g-4220g.pdf)

If you are concerned about the health of your hard drive, or can't boot from it I would suggest making a bootable CD or USB flash drive and use it to test your hard drive.  I like using [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) if you use the flash drive, or [Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.net/) if you use the CD option.  (you can actually use Hiren's boot CD on the flash drive)